# JavaScript /jQuery variable scope causing errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, global-variables, scope

I have a really simple snippet of code and a really (probably) simple change I need to make.

I can't access a variable that I need to in my jQuery script:

```
var Objects; // Used to store stuff
enable_reordering();

function enable_reordering()
{
    $('a.move-object').click(function(){

          Objects.moveMe = $(this);
          $('#image-title').text( $(Objects.moveMe).attr('data-child-title') );
          return false;
    });
}
```

When I try to change the value of `Objects.moveMe` to anything, my browser moans that Objects is not set. (`Error: Objects is undefined`).

How can I make it so that I can use variables in and out of functions throughout my entire script?

---

Update:

The error is caused by the line

```
$('#image-title').text( $(Objects.moveMe).attr('data-child-title') );
```

where I first try and use the variable.

Comment: Note that `$(Object.moveMe)` is basically doing `$($(this))`, which is superfluous.

Comment: I am not sure, but I think you need to use var Objects = new Object;

Comment: @pimvdb It'll be getting used in other functions, that's why it's needed. The example above is just to outline the problem I was having.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a scope issue. The problem is that, as the error says, `Objects` is `undefined`. It looks like you want to set a property of it, so initialize it as an object literal:

```
var Objects = {};
```

Currently, what you are trying to do is effectively:

```
undefined.moveMe = $(this);
```

When you declare a variable, its value is `undefined` until you assign some other value to it. By assigning an empty object literal to it, you can then set properties of that object.

Answer (score 3):

try: http://jsbin.com/ocodoz/

```
var a;
alert(a);
```

`a === undefined` But declared in the current scope..

Your Object have to be set to an object

```
var Objects = {};
```